# Agenda ou calendrier?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot

I'm looking at my calendar in a software package:

[image]

Should this be called an *agenda* or a *calendrier*?
From e.g. [Agendas et calendriers - Vivre le temps qui passe](https://www.ledevoir.com/societe/71326/agendas-et-calendriers-vivre-le-temps-qui-passe)  I get the impression I should use *agenda*, but if I e.g. look at the English language where *agenda* and *calendar* [are defined similarly](https://diffsense.com/diff/agenda/calendar), yet *calendar* is definitely the term to use. <sup>*</sup>
(This is for software translations)

<sup>* And in Dutch where we have *agenda* and *kalender*, we use *agenda* again ;-)</sup>

Comment: If you search on bol.com for "agenda" and "kalender", you get quite an explicit view of what an "agenda" and a "calendrier" are in French. In this case, as stated in the answers, it's clearly an agenda. Basically a "calendrier" usually doesn't specify hours, while an agenda does.

Comment: "Emploi du temps" can also be used.

Comment: Thanks for the replies; I'm not going to mark one as *the* correct answer.

Comment: @Lepticed *Emploi-du-temps* is almost only used in a school or academic context and is originally used to tell the day and start/end time of repetitive classes (every week or every other week) for a given grade. It is true that moving from paper to electronic made the *emplois du temps* more flexible, and they can now show the days of month and month itself while the original ones only showed the days of the week.

Comment: @jlliagre I know that it is almost only used in school or academic context. But it is the word that came to my mind when I saw the picture. I give it in comment, as it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Lepticed I have no doubt that you know but as you didn't state the context where *emploi du temps* is used, my comment was more for non native readers, including the OP, to be aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

***Agenda*** better suit the need.

A ***calendrier*** only shows the weekdays, generic events like public holidays, school vacations, saints of the day, seasons, moon phases and so on while an ***agenda*** is something used to schedule personal events, make sure they do not overlap. An ***agenda*** is a personal organizer, it shows hours while a ***calendrier*** smallest unit is usually a day.

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi un agenda est un carnet dans lequel on note les choses à faire organisées par dates et heures.

Un calendrier est plutôt une table des jours, semaines et mois avec parfois des indications pour chaque période: tel jour est un lundi, tel autre est la pleine lune, telle semaine est une période de vacances scolaires, etc.

Je dirais que les principales différences sont qu'un agenda est personnel et a vocation à être modifié alors qu'un calendrier a une portée plus générale et reste statique.

Comment: pour moi, si le nom du jour n'est pas indiqué, ca n'est pas un calendrier...